# Java Tilemaps using Cliping to increase framerate: What can go WRONG?

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics, tile

Conducting research before starting something is a good idea so I've been looking at the articles here on Stackverflow before beginning a project.

Now while looking up tilemaps one of the other questions lead me to one of the Java Tutorials, specifically this page ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html ) where something caught my eye, this:

```
private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {
    int OFFSET = 1;
    if ((squareX!=x) || (squareY!=y)) {
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
    } 
}
```

For those who don't know what's going on when paint is called a red square is drawn at squareX, squareY, this is the method that allow you to change squareX and squareY and it speeds up the redrawing process by telling Java to limit to area to to be redrawn to only the old and new locations (That's the two calls to repaint)

Now this sounds like something that I should use, when a tile is updated it's co-ordinates are repainted but tilemaps normally involve 2d arrays and looping through the entire array when painting, possibly involving multiple images at a single location and while most of the map isn't redrawn that could still slow it down.

So you add a flag to you tiles that notes whether or not something has changed that would result in it having a different appearance since the last time everything was drawn and only place images for tiles that have changed.

This works well until something like the window the graphics are drawn in goes through a minimize/maximum cycle, now every tile will need it's graphics updated but none will be flagged as such, resulting in a blank screen.

What's the BEST why to handle this?

And what else have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `repaint(int,int,int,int);` is two folder.

Firstly, there is no guarantee that only this area will actually be scheduled by for updating.  The `RepaintManager` may consolidate multiple repaint requests into a single request, combining the areas to be painted possibly making the area to be repainted much larger.

Secondly, all `repaint` requests are schedule back onto the Event Dispatching Thread, which means that it will bubble down to your `paintXxx` method anyway.

So, unless your `paintXxx` method is optimised to handle the update, it's not doing you any favours.

As you've also pointed out, you would actually need to be able to calculate which titles that be updated based on the clipping rectangle of the `Graphics` context.

A better approach might be to use a off screen buffer, which is updated in some background thread, as part of your game engine.  This would then be switched to the "active" buffer for painting to the screen when it is ready.

You could take advantage of the clipping at this time, to only render a small portion of the active buffer if you found updating the whole screen to inafficent

...IMHO...

There's actually a little bit of discussion about this in [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)